# i got this error after creating each django project and try to run the server

Tags: django

```
raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
```

django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20200301_0817 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('users', '0001_initial')

Comment: Have you made your first migrations? If not, try deleting all migration dirs in your project and make your first migration.

Comment: yes i have deleted the migration and re-migrate and got this error while running server in other projects too.

Comment: I think you must add `*migrations*` to your `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a reset of the `django_migrations` table, in your database, it stores the migrations previously made and its dependencies.
Also make sure you delete all previous migration files (inside migrations folder).

Viewing the files you currently have could help you better understand your situation.